Sefardi Tachanun in Ashkenazi Shul (and the converse) - Poresh Min Hatzibbur? If so, what to do?
The title captures the question perfectly. (Many modern*) Sefardi Tachanun procedures are very visibly different from standard Ashkenazi procedures.

Ashkenazim fall on their face
(Many modern) Sefardim stand and do Viddui

So what are the teshuvot about what one should Sefardim do in Ashkenazi shuls, and the converse?
* Thanks DoubleAA for bringing this; this difference didn't exist until recently. The question remains on what to do now.

https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Davening_with_a_Minyan_That_Uses_a_Different_Nusach#General_-_Lo_Titgodedu addresses “the teshuvot about what one should Sefardim do in Ashkenazi shuls, and the converse”

For the poskim in that link who think sefardim should go back to doing things the traditional way, the question is a non starter.

The Arukh Hashulchan (OC 651:22) suggests that there is no issue of separating from the congregation when waving Lulav in a different manner from most, since the Mishna (Sukka 3:9) tells us of certain rabbis who did just that. The Talmud (Megilla 22b) tells us of certain rabbis who didn't fall on their face in prayer even though the rest of the congregation did. Seemingly the same logic applies.
On the other hand, note the modern practice of many Sefardim to not fall on their face is rooted in a kabbalistic concern of not maintaining appropriate focus when reciting Psalm 25:1. There is no reason not to fall on one's face if supplicating using Psalm 6 for instance as Ashkenazim commonly do. There's also no reason a Sefardi can't choose to say Psalm 6 one time as there is no fixed text for Tachanun. A Sefardi who wants to say Psalm 25 as he is used to can always do so in addition to Psalm 6 (or any other supplication done while fallen).

Did sefardim always do viddui? If not, would sefardim who have adopted this be able to stop or is it a binding minhag? In either case, would doing viddui be poresh min hatzibbur by Ashkenazim given that it is standing and chest pounding, very different to sitting and falling on one's face
